# how to decrypt ECC in python (CC-Based Hybrid Encryption)

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I try to follow this article about ECC Hybrid Encryption, I did everything but I failed to send the public key to another side to decrypt the image.

ref: https://cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/ecc-encryption-decryption#ecc-based-hybrid-encryption-decryption-example-in-python

What I need exactly what should I do to decrypt the image when I try to use **ciphertextPubKey** as the library.

when I print the ciphertextPubKey in memory it came like that.

the result in run time working oky.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2unk9.png)

also I add necessary information(authTag,nonce,ciphertextPubKey) end of the file like that

```
D��d�nonce:c1b340952d625c29b733c18d747da1a1authTag:7d64322d11887ff7a660e7cac15182ddciphertextPubKey:0x73783af49ec67734e390f4e
```

```
(53416237437808318183671035859997439596368087928543682406945105437476683600844, 32944848609008475717230473932056561595117227191583483133382911397576230043540) on "brainpoolP256r1" => y^2 = x^3 + 56698187605326110043627228396178346077120614539475214109386828188763884139993x + 17577232497321838841075697789794520262950426058923084567046852300633325438902 (mod 76884956397045344220809746629001649093037950200943055203735601445031516197751)
```

Also, ciphertext PubKey is **ec.Point Object** when I print the type.

this is the link for the library:
https://github.com/alexmgr/tinyec

this is the function for decrypt

```
def decrypt_ECC(encryptedMsg, privKey):
    (ciphertext, nonce, authTag, ciphertextPubKey) = encryptedMsg
    sharedECCKey = privKey * ciphertextPubKey
    secretKey = ecc_point_to_256_bit_key(sharedECCKey)
    plaintext = decrypt_AES_GCM(ciphertext, nonce, authTag, secretKey)
    return plaintext
```

**The main question is How I can export these keys and send them to the receiver to decrypt?**

I tried to reverse the process to get the key I got the same key but there is one error

```
privKey = 73825439940174196720472396443747486663228376337080507389815193133315618892552
    pubKey = privKey * curve.g
    ciphertextPrivKey = secrets.randbelow(curve.field.n)
    ciphertextPubKeyY = ciphertextPrivKey * curve.g
```

```
ciphertextPubKey : b'0x6f31f88920caca9ba1d6507c58e0529e57c4d132fdbfc59f3f83f703f2881a4e1'


ciphertextPubKey : b'0x6f31f88920caca9ba1d6507c58e0529e57c4d132fdbfc59f3f83f703f2881a4e1'
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testEncryption.py", line 146, in <module>
    decryptedMsg = decrypt_ECC(encryptedMsg, privKey)
  File "testEncryption.py", line 59, in decrypt_ECC
    plaintext = decrypt_AES_GCM(ciphertext, nonce, authTag, secretKey)
  File "testEncryption.py", line 37, in decrypt_AES_GCM
    plaintext = aesCipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag)
  File "/home/yashazem/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_gcm.py", line 567, in decrypt_and_verify
    self.verify(received_mac_tag)
  File "/home/yashazem/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_gcm.py", line 508, in verify
    raise ValueError("MAC check failed")
ValueError: MAC check failed
```

Comment: So this is a fundamental tenet of public key encryption. You would post the public key somewhere so that anyone can get it and then verify that you have encrypted something with your private key. They also can encrypt something with your private key and then only you can decrypt it. That's why only you are supposed to have the private key, but they have the public key.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was I forget to convert that hex byte to bytes because this function.

```
'nonce': binascii.hexlify(encryptedMsg[1]),
```

so what I did just

```
 nonceValue = nonce.decode("utf8").split(":")[1].encode()
        authTagValue = authTag.decode("utf8").split(":")[1].encode()
```

it converts from

```
b'3de2718f718b23135f5a40fe1e737b61'
```

To

```
b'=\xe2q\x8fq\x8b#\x13_Z@\xfe\x1es{a'
```